# Join many MP3, OGG, and FLAC files into one WAV or FLAC

Tags: linux, audio, mp3, flac, ogg

I have 33 audio files, each about 11 seconds long, and I'd like to merge them into one lossless file. How can I do this efficiently (i.e. without cut-pasting in Audacity 33 times)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with `ffmpeg` and `sox`:

```
for i in *.mp3 *.ogg *.flac
do
  ffmpeg -i "$i" "$i.wav"
done

sox *.wav combined.wav
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help.

Comment: `sox` doesn't work for OGG: `/usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.2_1/bin/sox FAIL formats: no handler for detected file type 'opus'`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you want to merge them alphabetically, by filename:

```
for f in ./*.{ogg,flac,mp3}; do echo "file '$f'" >> inputs.txt; done
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt output.wav
```

The *for* loop puts all the filenames in a file called inputs.txt, one-per-line, and the second one uses [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org)'s [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join%2C%20merge%29%20media%20files#demuxer) to merge the files. It is possible to use printf instead of the loop like so:

```
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.{ogg,flac,mp3} > inputs.txt
```

Assuming a modern shell, you can also use command substitution to do the whole thing in a single line.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.{ogg,flac,mp3}) output.wav
```

Comment: I believe this is the 'correct' ffmepg answer as it will not re-encode anything.

Comment: Does not work if a file name contains `'`

Comment: ^ I'm talking about 1st command, didn't try other two yet.

Comment: I get an error when I attempt the one-liner, but this works for me:
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.flac; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) output.flac`

Comment: a) Edit the file inputs.txt if some files of the type (ogg,flac,mp3) do not exist.
b) If 'Unsafe file name' is reported then add the following parameter : -safe 0
example : ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i inputs.txt output.flac

Comment: @AndrewBurns No, it will reencode. And it is good, flac needs decoding to write correct duration and md5.

Comment: what if you want to concatenate only parts of any of the input files using -to and -ss?

Answer (score 4):

If you start with only lossless files, you can use use [shntool](http://www.etree.org/shnutils/shntool/):

```
shntool join *.flac
```

Comment: I get this error: `shntool [join]: warning: unsupported format 0xfffe (Unknown) while processing file: [file1.flac]`

Answer (score 2):

However, be aware that the shntool join will insist on joining them in collating sequence (alphabetical) order EVEN IF you specify them otherwise.

```
shntool join fileB.flac fileA.flac
```

will put A before B.

You can either rename the files first or use the -r parameter ("-r ask" will prompt for the order).

Frankly I find this irritating...

Also you can force the output mode, so if you're joining FLACs:

```
shntool join *.flac -o flac
```

will result in joined.flac rather than joined.wav

Comment: `-r none` will turn off the reordering.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Sound Juicer that comes with Ubuntu writes broken FLAC files, which result in no MD5 signature in the file. MAKE A COPY of the directory containing the files you want to concatenate, then run the script below.

`echo fixing broken FLAC files

find . -type f|grep .flac$ |while read file

do

   flac -f --decode "$file"  -o temp.wav

   flac -f -8 temp.wav -o "$file"

done

rm temp.wav`

Then run
`shntool join *.flac`
 as above.